# Running Java program using mvn through command line

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run my java program `TopicPublisher.java` via command line. There are several dependencies specified through Maven.

In the directory with the `pom.xml` file, I ran the following commands: `mvn clean`, `mvn package`, and `java -cp target/SOM_Enrichment-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar TopicPublisher`.

I get the following error:

`Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: om/solacesystems/jcsmp/JCSMPStreamingPublishEventHandler`

Below is a screenshot of my directory tree:

[image: directory tree]

Any ideas how to solve this?

**[EDIT]**

**Pom File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>CAMM</groupId>
<artifactId>SOM_Enrichment</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.solacesystems</groupId>
        <artifactId>sol-jcsmp</artifactId>
        <version>[10,)</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Pom jdk version and the jdk on your computer?

Comment: @Alec I didn't specify the pom jdk version; not sure what the default is but I think it's the one I'm currently using which is the jdk on my computer. the version is 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program loads classes from the `com.solacesystems` dependency in your `pom.xml`, but your classpath only contains your build artifact jar. Build a fat jar, as @Kerry suggests, or use the exec-maven-plugin to run from the command line. From within your project directory (where you execute `mvn package`), execute:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=TopicPublisher
```

The plugin builds the classpath argument from the dependencies defined in your pom. See https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ for more options.

Comment: oh wow this works! seems like the issue is that my dependencies are not in the jar but i tried Kerry's suggestion to no avail.. :-/

Comment: This runs the application but does it build a JAR with third party dependencies?

Comment: i don't think it does @Kerry. i appreciate your help but i think i have to give Kerry the answer. thanks so much though :)

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your full `POM.xml` I am assuming you have not build the final artifact to be a 'fat jar'. By this I mean that the JAR not only contains your own classes but all the third party dependencies.

You would need to use something like the [Maven assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or the [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)to do this for you. From the screenshot though I see you are using IntelliJ so you should also be able to run through your IDE obviously for just testing purposes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i followed the instructions and updated my pom.xml file. the error still persists though..

Comment: I seem to remember I needed to use the shade plugin. Have you tried that instead of the assembly plugin?